# Java - Which is the best locking method to use for a booking system

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Say if I want to create a Web based booking system for a Multiplex with 2 halls each running 4 shows a day. I want to synchronize booking of seats for each show.

- Person A tries to reserve 2PM show in Hall A
- Person B tries to reserve 6PM show in Hall A
- Person C tries to reserve 2PM show in Hall B
- Person D tries to reserve 2PM show in Hall A
- Person E tries to reserve 6PM show in Hall B

Of all these, I want only Person D to wait for person A to complete the booking as they are reserving for same hall and same showtime. All others should be able to book concurrently

My Business layer method has hallName, showId as parameter

```
public int createBooking(String hallName, int showId){

  //check if there are any available seats
  //access DAO layer to create booking

  return bookingId;
}
```

I cannot synchronize this method as that will make all bookings wait for one another.

I cannot use semaphore because it dont acquire/release lock based on a parameter. I somehow have to pass in a parameter while acquiring/releasing the lock or create a queue for booking based on the show id. 
I dont want to hardcode the number of locks because the no of Halls and shows may change over time.

Is there a way to do in Java 6? (Framework - Spring 3 / Server - Websphere7)

There may be a simple approach but I am afraid I am not thinking in right direction.

Comment: If you're using a database, why not rely on it to do your locking? Also, be aware that you cannot control whether Person D waits for Persion A, or vice-versa, or whether there is contention between them at all.

Comment: Have you considered using actors? Having a 'booking actor' per hall+show will effectively queue those requests while the system remains high concurrent. See akka.

Comment: I would not use any Java synchronization, but instead as soon as someone starts to reserve a seat, reserve it for them. If they cancel, put it back in the pool of available seats. Also, since this is web based, they might just close their browser, so you need to have a time stamp on these provisional reservations, and periodically release any that are over `X` minutes old.

Comment: @kdgregory Yes I am using Sybase ASE in backend. But I have to insert/update data in many tables while booking and there are issues with locking on peak loads. I have to synchronize the resources before hitting the database.

Comment: @DavidConrad - your comment is better by far than the current answers; I'll upvote you (after dinner) if you make it one and expand

Comment: @ArunChristopher - I'm guessing that you have some table that keeps track of the number of open seats for each hall/show. If yes, then you can basically do a "compare and swap" decrement operation against that table to acquire the reservation. *Only if that succeeds* do you proceed to update other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public int createBooking(String hallName, int showId){
    synchronized ((hallName + showId).intern()) {
        //check if there are any available seats
        //access DAO layer to create booking
        return bookingId;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks simple. Any issues with this this approach?

Comment: I've used it in different circumstances over the years. It's a somewhat non-obvious way to achieve lock striping of an arbitrary granularity. The only issue might be around having an extremely large number of distinct (hallName + showId) strings, which can exhaust memory when interned.

Comment: This works right up to the point where you decide to use the same string for locking somewhere else in your program.

Comment: I will be using the lock only at one place. Does it have to be be interned? What if I dont use intern and just create a lock with literal `hallName+showId`?

Comment: This approach will fail in clustered or load-balanced environment, where you have more than one JVM.

Comment: @Arun Christopher: `hallName+showId` will create a new `String` instance on every invocation. So only using `intern()` ensures that the same combination of `hallName` and `showId` yields to the same instance and hence the same lock. However, this is still dangerous. The contention might be higher than expected when names ending with a number are introduced, e.g. the `hallName` is `A1` but as [Jk1 has pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664644/java-which-is-the-best-locking-method-to-use-for-a-booking-system#comment36360876_23664771) it can be even worse…

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at Event Sourcing for his kind of stuff in real life. It's a kind of problem which is quite a classical example of this architecture.

I'm not going to explain the full model here, and I will even betray it, in order to be short:

I would create BookingRequested events, with a unique ID (UUID maybe, or database-provided) and a timestamp, and store those in the database (or in a in-memory queue).

Then a query processor would work on them. It could lock on the in-memory object, or you might even decide that only one thread would work on one room, extracting the unprocessed requests for this particular room.
If you can't, and have distant systems working on the same data, the solution might be optimistic locking.

when a decision is taken on the booking, it's a new event, which you will store in the database too. It will contain the reference of the original request, and the result.

Microsoft has a free pdf book, "Exploring CQRS and Event Sourcing", with a very complete example with a similar context (a system for booking places at various conferences).